# ASP.NET MVC DI with controller action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, action-filter

I am using asp.net mvc controller with constructor injected service `IMyService`. `MyService` (implements `IMyService`) uses some contextual information in its constructor. This contextual information supplied from different third party web site. Contextual information is required for creating `MyService` instance.

Controller's action filter uses some logic in order to determine, if this contextual information is available. If not, then request is redirected to another web site. The problem is, that controller constructor is called by IoC container before controller's filter. As a result `MyService` throws exception if contextual information is not provided.

How to workaround this situation?

**UPD**:
It seems that `DelegatingHandler` is a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a quick workaround you could use remove the `IMyService` from your Constructor and instead add it in as a property of your controller and use your IoCs Service Locator to resolve it when it is needed by a method in the controller.

Comment: To do this, I need to inject container into the constructor, it's not a good idea I think. But, only like workaround may be this is possible.